# How do I SQL Randomize each column individually

Tags: sql, join, select, random

let's say my table looks like this.

```
Input: Table Person
ID | first_name | last_name | age | gender
1  | Robert     | Müller    | 34  | m
2  | Jannis     | Fischer   | 19  | m
3  | Monika     | Schmid    | 54  | f
```

The purpose is to "create" data with the table itself. I want to randomize centraint columns of my table and put them back together.

I want to randomize first_name with gender that they will always be the same together and last_name and age can be randomized by their columns.

```
Output: Table Person

ID | first_name | last_name | age | gender
1  | Robert     | Schmid    |  34 | m
2  | Monika     | Müller    |  54 | f
3  | Jannis     | Fischer   |  19 | m
```

I tried to Join two select statements but this didn't really work.

I could be something like this:

```
Select ID, first_name, gender From Person TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(10);

UNION

Select ID, last_name, age From Person TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(10);
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres? Maybe this: https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer is something for you (e.g. the `shuffle_column()` function)

Comment: `UNION` is used to combine rows from two tables *with the same schema*.

Comment: Yeah so UNION should be right but its not I mean i want to join the table with itself. And im on a HANA

Comment: `UNION` is *not* right, at least not how you've written it: that will produce (in anything) a table where one column has first & last names and another has genders & ages.

Comment: Ah yeah true but what can i use then ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to split the names and age/gender randomly.  Assuming you don't want duplicates, then you can use `row_number()` and a random number generator.  You haven't specified the database, but the idea is:

```
select seqnum as id,
       pn.first_name, pn.last_name, pd.age, pd.gender
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
      from persons
     ) pn join
     (select p.*, row_number() over (order by random()) as seqnum
      from persons
     ) pd 
     on pn.seqnum = pd.seqnum;
```

Comment: Cheers Mate tooke me a while but it was the right approach from you thanks